# Extracting "quarter" along with its corresponding year from text in R

Tags: r

I have some text data which looks like:

```
    text id
1 For the fourth quarter of 2017, based on current information, the results for the second quarter of 2005 showed  1
2                                 The third quarter of 2019 is available with figures showing 1234 and also 87653  2
3                                                      Some text which is skipped over but also has a number 2017  3
4                                                                           first results for the quarter of 2010  4
```

I want to extract some of the information from it such as the first, second, third and fourth quarter but I also want to extract the first 4 digit number after the words first,...,fourth quarter (since it corresponds to the year the text is referring to.

I can do something like:

```
data %>% 
  mutate(
    quarterMentioned = str_extract_all(text, "first|second|third|fourth")
)
```

Which extracts the quarters from the data but I cannot seem to get the corresponding year.

Expected output:

```
data.frame(
  firstQuarterYear = c(NA,NA,NA, "first, 2010"),
  secondQuarterYear = c("second, 2005", NA, NA, NA),
  thirdQuarterYear = c(NA, "third, 2019", NA, NA),
  fourthQuarterYear = c("fourth, 2017", NA, NA, NA)
                  )

  firstQuarterYear secondQuarterYear thirdQuarterYear fourthQuarterYear
1             <NA>      second, 2005             <NA>      fourth, 2017
2             <NA>              <NA>      third, 2019              <NA>
3             <NA>              <NA>             <NA>              <NA>
4      first, 2010              <NA>             <NA>              <NA>
```

Data:

```
    data <- data.frame(
  text = c("For the fourth quarter of 2017, based on current information, the results for the second quarter of 2005 showed",
           "The third quarter of 2019 is available with figures showing 1234 and also 87653",
           "Some text which is skipped over but also has a number 2017",
           "first results for the quarter of 2010"),
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should indeed use a regular expression and tailor it to your needs.
Here I used the following expression:

```
(?i)(first|second|third|fourth|1st|2nd|3rd|4th).*?quarter\\s+of\\s+(\\d+)
```

`(?i)` enters case insensitive mode

The first capturing group is `(first|second|third|fourth|1st|2nd|3rd|4th)` and looks for either first, second, third, fourth, 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th

`.*?` looks for any characters until

quarter of

`(\\d+)` is the second capturing group and looks for digits

Allowing for any characters between first/second.. and quarter allows you to capture also "first results for the quarter".

```
library(stringr)

res = lapply(str_match_all(df$text,"(?i)(first|second|third|fourth|1st|2nd|3rd|4th).*?quarter\\s+of\\s+(\\d+)"), function(x) str_c(x[,2],x[,3],sep=","))

[[1]]
[1] "fourth,2017" "second,2005"

[[2]]
[1] "third,2019"

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "first,2010"
```

This will give you a list, and you can then modify it to get your desired output format.
Your current output dataframe format has the issue that it would not be able to handle a given quarter for more than one year for one id, unless you paste them together.